# Can I add multiple coordinates to /testfor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am just wondering if I can add multiple coordinates to one part because this is an example on what I mean (note this is in command blocks) : `testfor @p[x=x1,y=y1,z=z1 z2,r=r1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Use two commands instead.

Also, consider if you really need `/testfor`, it's usually not needed and got removed in 1.13.

Comment: Fabian Roiling, it didn't get removed, it's available on Xbox one if you had taken the time to research it

Comment: @UnknownTheAnonymous Java Edition 1.13 does not have ``testfor``. it was replaced with more ``execute`` checks. you never specified that you're on Xbox One, so it's easy to assume that you meant Java. if you did mean Xbox, please put the appropriate tag on it, either [minecraft-bedrock-edition], or [minecraft] and [xbox-one].

Comment: And people wondered why I wanted to put "DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR BEDROCK EDITION!" at the beginning of the tag info…

Comment: Wrigglenite i just suggested that edit since i can't answer because i have apparently been blocked from posting answers (or even questions) for god knows why

Comment: @UnknownTheAnonymous I replied to your edit suggestion here, please read it: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/351060/how-to-prevent-the-switching-of-items-inside-the-hotbar-in-vanilla-minecraft-1/351062#comment493727_351062

Comment: I can't answer and that was for if he was on Xbox, thats the thing, like i said "it doesn't stop them from switching items because there are no other items for them to switch to" basically saying that they can't switch items because they are getting the item removed then replaced with a different item thus making it so they can't switch items when they have none to switch to but one to be stuck with

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, but he's talking about pressing the number keys or scrolling to change the selected hotbar slot. You can't change anything about that with commands. And unless you've done anything bad, you can always post answers.