# How to prevent the switching of items inside the hotbar in vanilla minecraft [1.12.2]?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a set of commands I could use which would allow for me to prevent a player from switching items? So if their "selectedItem" slot is 1, they can't switch the slot to 2.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Not much more to say here, there's just no way to do it, except for writing a custom mod for both client and server.

I recommend instead thinking about what you want to really do. For example, maybe it could work to just move the item in the hotbar with the selected slot. Or just give the player 9 identical items. Or make whatever you're doing not dependent on the selected slot. Or …

Comment: @UnknownTheAnonymous Firstly, please don't answer questions by exchanging an existing answer with something completely different. There is an answer text box, just use that. Secondly, your solution has nothing to do with the question. This is not about removing or adding items and also has nothing to do with the location of the player. Thirdly, your solutions doesn't even work, `/testfor` was removed.